# How to deploy a Hyperledger Fabric app

Tags: api, hyperledger, hyperledger-fabric

I have my chaincode, 4 peers and one orderer ready. I am able to query my chaincode through the CLI, but how can I query it using an API and how can I deploy it as a webapp. Can anybody please comment on it?

Answer (score 4):

There are several SDK provided so you can leverage them in your application.

1. [Node SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-node)
2. [Java SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java)
3. [Go SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-go)
4. [Python SDK](https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py)

You can pick one of these up to your convenience, for example you here a short example of how you can use Java SDK to query chaincode:

```
    // Get an instance of Hyperledger Fabric client
    final HFClient client = HFClient.createNewInstance();

    // Set default crypto suite for HF client
    client.setCryptoSuite(CryptoSuite.Factory.getCryptoSuite());
```

Now you need to setup user content to provide user name and crypto material which identifies the user in his organization.

```
    // Set user context
    client.setUserContext(new User() {

        public String getName() {
            return "testUser";
        }

        public Set<String> getRoles() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getAccount() {
            return null;
        }

        public String getAffiliation() {
            return null;
        }

        // Enrollment is an interface to retrieve certificate and private key of the user in context
        public Enrollment getEnrollment() {
            return new Enrollment() {
                public PrivateKey getKey() {
                       return privateKey;
                }

                public String getCert() {
                    return certificate;
                }
            };
        }

        public String getMspId() {
            return "Org1MSP";
        }
    });
```

Next need to create an instance of the channel in context.

```
    // Create new channel
    final Channel channel = client.newChannel("mychannel");

    // Setup ordering service
    channel.addOrderer(client.newOrderer("orderer0", "grpc://localhost:7050"));
    // COnfigure endorsing peers
    channel.addPeer(client.newPeer("peer0", "grpc://localhost:7051"));

    // Finally initialize the channel
    channel.initialize();
```

Finally we ready to send transaction proposal.

```
    // Create transaction request
    final TransactionProposalRequest proposalRequest = client.newTransactionProposalRequest();

    final ChaincodeID chaincodeID = ChaincodeID.newBuilder()
            .setName("myCC")
            .setVersion("1.0")
            .setPath("github.com/some_package/package/chaincode/myCC")
            .build();

    // chaincode name
    proposalRequest.setChaincodeID(chaincodeID);
    // chaincode function to execute
    proposalRequest.setFcn("some_function");
    // timeout
    proposalRequest.setProposalWaitTime(TimeUnit.SECONDS.toMillis(10));
    // arguments for chaincode function
    proposalRequest.setArgs( // Set arguments based on CC );

    // Sending transaction proposal
    final Collection<ProposalResponse> responses = channel.sendTransactionProposal(proposalRequest);

    CompletableFuture<BlockEvent.TransactionEvent> txFuture = channel.sendTransaction(responses, client.getUserContext());
```

Getting execution results back:

```
    BlockEvent.TransactionEvent event = txFuture.get();

    System.out.println(event.toString());
```

With other SDK code will look pretty similar, here you can take a look on similar [Go SDK example](https://github.com/C0rWin/pgdays/blob/master/chaincode/client/client.go).

Comment: I would add that there is a Python SDK as well. https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-py

Comment: @ArtemBarger Can you share any link for the documentation regarding Fabric-Java-SDK In other words suggest me how to start writing java code for Hyperledger-Fabric

Comment: I've started by simply looking into examples here: https://github.com/hyperledger/fabric-sdk-java/tree/master/src/test/java/org/hyperledger/fabric/sdkintegration. If you need exact details, like maven pom.xml, how to build it and what dependencies, please create a new question, since it's pretty hard to explain it in comments.

Comment: another possibility is to seek for a help in Rocket.Chat channel for java-sdk: https://chat.hyperledger.org/channel/fabric-sdk-java

Answer (score 1):

Here is the go-to [tutorial](https://hyperledger-fabric.readthedocs.io/en/latest/write_first_app.html) from documentation showing how to write an application via Node.js SDK that queries the Fabric ledger.